# get only domain name excluding the .com www and sub domain

Tags: php

i have to get only the domain names from some website list given to me. I have to take only the shop name excluding the .com , www and sub domain . similarly i have to take only one shopname and insert into db

eg. the list is

```
shopping.indiatimes.com
shopping.indiatimes.com
shopping.indiatimes.com
www.infibeam.com
adexmart.com
deals.sulekha.com    
deals.sulekha.com
www.ebay.in
deals.ebay.in
shop.seventymm.com
www.homeshop18.com
www.buytheprice.com
www.snapdeal.com
www.aircel.com
www.tradus.com
www.infibeam.com
www.futurebazaar.com
www.tradus.com
www.shoppingmantra.com
camera.zoomin.com
www.homeshop18.com
```

so here i want only the domain name like , indiatimes , ebay , tradus , zoomin..etc.

Comment: `$domain = parse_url($rows['sitelink']);
        $host = $domain['host'];        
        $exp  = explode('.' , $host);        
        $domainname = ($exp[1]); `  but i am getting many same shops. i want to take only one shop and inset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$domain = parse_url("www.domainnames.com");
    $host = $domain['host'];       
     $exp  = explode('.' , $host);        
                if(isset($exp[2])){        
                $domainname = ($exp[1]);
                }else {           
                    $domainname = ($exp[0]);
                }
                $a []= $domainname;  

      $uniquenames = (array_unique($a));    
      print_r($uniquenames);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($domains as $domain)
   echo implode('', array_slice(explode('.', $domain), -2, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be completed by doing a string explode and then taking the second last array element.

```
$array = explode(".", "www.snapdeal.com");

$count = count($array);
$value = $array[$count - 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url_to_check = "http://www.shopping.indiatimes.com";
$url1 = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $url_to_check);
$domain = implode('', array_slice(explode('.', $url1), -2, 1));
echo $domain; //this will echo indiatimes
```